# How to transform a dense matrix to rdd in Scala Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have dense matrix:

```
-0.1503191229976037 -0.17794560268465542 0.3372516173766848
-0.6265768782935162 -0.6986084179343495 -1.6553741696973772
```

How do I convert it to RDD of format:

```
0, 0, -0.1503191229976037
0, 1, -0.17794560268465542
0, 2, 0.3372516173766848
1, 0, -0.6265768782935162
1, 1, -0.6986084179343495
1, 2, -1.6553741696973772
```

The first two values are indices.

The type of my input matrix is: 
`org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseMatrix`

The expected output type is: `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[scala.Tuple2[scala.Tuple2[Int, Int], Double]]`

How do I do it on Spark using Scala?

Comment: You've probably been downvoted because of [noattempt](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). Also, you should use [Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to format your questions.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Will keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your vectors are represented by the actual data structure `Vector`:

```
val vectors: List[Vector[Double]] = ???
val vecsWithIndices = for {
  (vIdx, vec) <- Stream.from(0).zip(vectors)
  i <- 0 until 3
} yield (vIdx, i, vec(i))

val rdd = spark.parallelize(vecsWithIndices)
```

The `Stream.from(0)` generates the index of the vector, the `i` runs over components of the vector.

Comment: @Zaman If this information is not specific to this answer, then you should add clarifications by editing your question, there is a little gray 'edit' button.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it like this:

```
val denseMatrix=for (
        i <- 0 to 2;
        j <- 0 to 2
      ) yield ((i, j), z.apply(i,j))
val rdd = sc.parallelize(z1)
```

Please let me know if there is a better way. Thank you.